# Provide data such as holder name or address to PayPal JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk

I am using the PayPal JavaScript SDK as described on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

As you can see on this page, there is a "Try the buttons" header and a "MasterCard" logo for example. If you click on "MasterCard" a window pops up, where the user can provide his name, address an so on, see image:

[image: Paypal]

I already have all this data from my customer and want to pass it to PayPal, so the form is pre-filled. I know, the user could change the values in the pop-up, but this is OK.

Unfortunately, I did not see any params/methods to provide this information to PayPal. But this must be possible, right?

Please help! :-)

Thank you,
schube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got (most) of it working (thanks to the pointer of Vikramjit).

The telephone number is still a problem, but I do not need it.

Here is a working example: https://gist.github.com/schube/84811d3a6520bbec5563673730c2440f and here is "playground" for easy experiments: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Follow these links for further information.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/update-order-details/#

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch

Comment: Thank you, but this is about the REST API. I am using the JavaScript SDK, which is something else, as I understood it.

Comment: Thank you, for pointing me in the correct direction. See other post down here.